# Stuck on RASPBMC November update

Tags: raspbmc, update

For the life of me I can't figure out why my Pi won't update to the December update of RASPBMC. I've tried forcing the update as explained on RASPBMC website but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I finally managed to sort it. Something I thought I had already tried.

Comment: sudo mv /scripts/upd_sys/ftr.sh /tmp/
sudo rm /scripts/upd_sys/*.sh
sudo mv /tmp/ftr.sh /scripts/upd_sys/
sudo wget http://svn.stmlabs.com/svn/raspbmc/testing/update-system/getfile.sh -O /scripts/upd_sys/getfile.sh

Comment: Scrap that. It did force and update but I'm still on the November version.

Answer (score 1):

raspbmc along with most distributions for the raspberrypi are fast changing and sometimes buggy (aka not old-stable). Just backup the data, install the latest version ([OSMC](https://osmc.tv/download/)), and restore the date.